# Appending string to array element in awk

Tags: arrays, awk

Given the following input

```
line1
line2
line3
```

would it be possible to append them all into a single array element and then output them the as

```
line1
line2
line3
```

with a single print statement? Semi-pseudo-code: `awk '{[append $0 to a[test]}; END {print a[test]}' file1`

A more complicated but more practical example problem is given two files, file 1 is:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and file2 is:

```
linea
lineb
linec
```

how would I produce output like so:

```
linea
line1
line2
line3
lineb
line1
line2
line3
linec
line1
line2
line3
```

My assumption that this would require an array is what is underlining my original question.

A couple of tests such as a[test]+=$0 and a[test]=a[test]+$0 have predictably failed.

Comment: yes, possible. show a complete example pls.

Comment: Let me know if you require more expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ awk '{
    a[1]=a[1] (a[1]==""?"":ORS) $1  # "append them all into a single array element"
} 
END {
    print a[1]                      # "output them - - with a single print statement"
}' file
line1
line2
line3
```

And for the latter part:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{
    a[NR]=$1; next
}
{
    b[FNR]=$1
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) {
        print a[i]
        for(j=1;j<=length(b);j++)
            print b[j]
    }
}
' file2 file1
linea
line1
line2
line3
lineb
line1
line2
line3
linec
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: your codes are very clear. however, you applied the worst time&space complexity Time: O(m*n), Space: O(m+n)  one of `a[NR] , b[FNR]` hashtable is not necessary, since awk processes input line by line. You don't have to save data in memory and loop thru them later.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a=$0;next}{print;printf "%s", a}'  RS="\0" f1 RS="\n" f2
```

Test:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
line1
line2
line3

==> f2 <==
linea
lineb
linec

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a=$0;next}{print;printf "%s", a}'  RS="\0" f1 RS="\n" f2
linea
line1
line2
line3
lineb
line1
line2
line3
linec
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: .. a bit of explaining or even pretty-printing for those starting to learn awk would be even more helpful : )